# Digital signatures with Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, digital-signature

I need help with digital signatures in ruby. What I'm aiming to do is have the application on a users computer receive a file digitally signed from me. The user application must then, without using any gems, verify the file is valid and read it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You might want to add more detail to your question. It seems very broad.

Answer (score 0):

With digital signatures this question can help
[Digital signature verification with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999096/digital-signature-verification-with-openssl)

Answer (score 0):

Most governments with working electronic signature schemas have desktop apps that allow verifying signed files. 
Estonia has one of the most advances softwares that can be isntalled from https://installer.id.ee/

Depending on the country of the receiver user there might be more optimized applications available.