# GOST digital signature verification with OpenSSL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl, gost3410

I have my certificate, source document, detached signature in Base64 format. Signature created by UEC (Universal Electronic Card - Russian smart card project) on Windows in CryptoARM program (I think [GOST hash function is used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_%28hash_function%29)).

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and have installed OpenSSL 1.0.1e (GOST support is included by default AFAIK).

I've installed UEC CA sertificate in Ubuntu CA store:

```
sudo cp ~/uec/uec.cer /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/uec.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

And console verification succeeds (sure if file wasn't changed):

```
$ openssl smime -verify -engine gost -inform DER -in ~/uec/to_be.txt.sig -content ~/uec/to_be.txt 
engine "gost" set.
Verification successful
Original file contents goes here
```

So, I'm trying to do validation in Ruby (2.0.0 and 2.1.0), as noted in this question: [Digital signature verification with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999096/digital-signature-verification-with-openssl)

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::Engine.load
engine = OpenSSL::Engine.by_id('gost')

cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
cert_store.set_default_paths
my_cert = File.read('/home/envek/uec/envek-b64.cer')
data = File.read('/home/envek/uec/to_be.txt')
signature = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(File.read('/home/envek/uec/to_be.txt.der.sig'))

signature.verify([my_cert], cert_store, data, OpenSSL::PKCS7::DETACHED || OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
# => false
signature
# => #<OpenSSL::PKCS7:0x00000002168918 @data="\xEF\xBB\xBF\xD0\xAD\xD1\x82\xD0\xBE \xD1\x84\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB9\xD0\xBB, \xD0\xBA\xD0\xBE\xD1\x82\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD1\x8B\xD0\xB9 \xD1\x8F \xD0\xBF\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB4\xD0\xBF\xD0\xB8\xD1\x88\xD1\x83", @error_string="unsupported algorithm">
```

So, I really don't know why it's just returns false, does my engine loading impacts anything or not. How to say `PKCS7#verify` to use correct algorithm, provided by GOST engine?

Any ideas?

Files:

- My certificate: https://www.dropbox.com/s/16pvqwyd58h93u0/envek-b64.cer
- UEC CA certificate: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vylglojbrqk5uww/uec_b64.cer
- Original file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciw1tr63eullhrx/to_be.txt
- Signature: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kx77qdaoesi6gf/to_be.txt.sig

P.S. To make OpenSSL work properly next steps are required (found [here](http://www.opennet.ru/openforum/vsluhforumID10/5170.html)):

This string should be added at most top of `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def
```

These strings should be added at most bottom of `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

```
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section
[engine_section]
gost = gost_section
[gost_section]
default_algorithms = ALL
engine_id = gost
```

After that next command should show next output:

```
$ openssl ciphers | tr ":" "\n" | grep GOST
GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89
GOST94-GOST89-GOST89
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird thing, I've just tried to call `OpenSSL::Engine#set_default` method with value of `0xFFFF` on it. Just:

```
engine.set_default(0xFFFF)
```

And it works!!!

[Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Engine.html#method-i-set_default) is absolutely unclear about it. What it does, what flags it receives as values? Anyone, explain me, please.

Comment: If you want to use GOST for all RSA operations you have to set them 'as default'. 
By calling `engine.set_default(0xFFFF)` you refers all operations such as symmetric cryptography, hash algorithms, dh algorithm params etc. to your engine. You can set them separately by using different constants.
[see source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/engine.h#L105-L116)
`0xFFFF` refers to initialize all RSA operations.